# Least painful way to gather a system state snapshot (memory %, HD space, etc) in .NET app?

Tags: c#, .net, resources, reporting

We have an app that is getting reports out 'in the wild' of slowing down, locking up, and other unwanted behaviors after many hours of running. Of course this hasn't occurred in the development and staging environments.

Looking for a way of collecting as much system information as we can from within the app (every 10-15 minutes or so) and then report this via a web service we already have set up. This will either rule in or rule out a resource issue as it relates to systems' vital signs.

Thinking this wheel has probably been invented already... Is there a reusable library normally used for tech support environments or something similar that would save us the time querying individual WMI objects and so forth? Suggestions welcome.

Comment: If you want to write far less code you might try shelling out to the "system information" tool...  Start...all programs...accessories...System Tools...System Information.

Answer (score 1):

Why would it have to be from within the app?

You can monitor and log various performance counters using PerfMon.

For a more in-depth answer, see http://dotnetdebug.net/2005/06/30/perfmon-your-debugging-buddy/.